# Odd keystroke sequence cant be deactivated?

Tags: keyboard

So I turn on my computer today and try to type the letters "php" but it automatically turns to this "₱", the Philippine currency symbol. So far Ive tried:

  Checking keyboard settings and region
1. Trying my wired apple keyboard and logitech wireless
2. Tested the Keyboard viewer and noticed something change in the function keys really fast, i recorded it and noticed the F16 key appeared which is not even used on my Logitech, my main keyboard
3. Tried turning Fn keys off and on
4. Tried Resetting NVRAM
5. Reinstalled OSX Sierra
6. Tried remapping with two programs, Karabiner and Better Touch Tool, which when recorded in Better Touch showed the actual keys being hit as phpv

This is driving me nuts. Anyone with a clue whats going on?

Examples:
 https://satori-design.d.pr/ldRMcJ
 https://satori-design.d.pr/QHy1Lr

Comment: Have you checked the Text Replacement settings?   For Apple that is in system preferences/keyboard/text/ replace with.  For 3rd party apps like Office it will be somewhere inside the app.  What apps are you talking about actually?  Do you have any 3rd party text replacement apps running?

Comment: Yes I checked there. It happens in every app and with both 3rd party wireless and Apple wired keyboards.

Comment: Are you sure you are not running something like typeit4me, textexpander, typiniator?  I don't think this could have anything to do with keyboards.

Answer (score 1):

So I wasnt able to find the cause, and last time I tried to use a clean account and bring over library prefs, etc it brought the problem back with it. I went nuclear and wiped my computer and started new. Pain in the ass but fixed the problem.